# How to explode pandas column values that are a list into separate features

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, pandas-groupby

So, I have a csv that I imported via terminal and it contains:

- RIVER_ID (unique river id for the whole water body)
- FEATURE_ID (unique ID for feature)
- value (name)
- count (count of name)

I had several values in a list of names as well as several FEATURE_ID values in a list grouped to a unique RIVER_ID. I managed to clean the value list and now I want to explode every FEATURE_ID into its own row and append RIVER_ID and value to it. But the explode() function is not giving me the expected results. It just explodes the list but keeps it as a string separated by ','. I am doing this because I was transferring names from linear to polygonal source and every polygonal river is made of several individual features (with unique FEATURE_IDs) but they have a RIVER_ID that marks all those individual features as one river. I managed to conflate the name only to some features so the idea is to group by RIVER_ID to transfer the name to all of the other features with the same RIVER_ID. So I want to keep the original geometry without dissolving and similar.

```
import pandas as pd
from sys import argv

input = argv[1]
# izlaz = argv[2]

df = pd.read_csv(input)
with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None, 'display.max_columns', None):  # more options can be specified also
    df_g = df.groupby(["HIDRO_ID"], as_index=False)[ 'value', 'count', 'HY_DTM_ID'].agg(lambda x: list(x))
    df_g['count'] = df_g.apply(lambda x: df_g['count'].max())

    i = 0
    for i, red in zip(range(0, len(df_g['value'])), df_g['value']):
        # print(red[0])
        # print(red)
        if len(red) > 1:
            if type(red[0]) == float:
                # print("Success")
                red[0] = red[1]
                red = red[0]
                # print(red)
                df_g['value'][i] = red

            elif type(red[-1]) == float:
                red[-1] = red[0]
                red = red[0]
                df_g['value'][i] = red
            i += 1

    df_final = df_g[['HIDRO_ID', 'value', 'count', 'HY_DTM_ID']]
    print(df_final.head(20))
    # print(df_g.explode('HY_DTM_ID'))
    df_final = df_g.explode('HY_DTM_ID')
    print(df_final.head(20))
    #
    #
    df_final.to_csv("river_names_changed.csv")
```

Example:

- RIVER_ID = 3
- FEATURE_ID = [439823, 448765, 487654]
- value = [nan, Danube, Danube]

After cleanup:

- RIVER_ID = 3
- FEATURE_ID = [439823, 448765, 487654]
- value = [Danube]

After explode():

- RIVER_ID = 3
- FEATURE_ID = 439823, 448765, 487654
- value = Danube

Desire after explode:

- RIVER_ID = 3
- FEATURE_ID = 439823
- value = Danube
- RIVER_ID = 3
- FEATURE_ID = 448765
- value = Danube
- RIVER_ID = 3
- FEATURE_ID = 487654
- value = Danube

Hope this is making it clear enough.

Comment: It seems some data related problem, is possible share rela data in dict in question? `d = df_final.head(20).to_dict('l')` and `print (d)` ?

Comment: It seems that it is a data problem. The HY_DTM_ID are read as string type since they come from csv and are separated by ',' so it can't read them as a list in csv. Not sure how to bypass this. What do you think? Should I try to reshape the input data and how or should I maybe explode and than again create lists of integers by separating with .split(",") and joining into a list again.

Comment: exactly, try convert it to lists by split.

Comment: Hey, so I did manage to split it using the df.str.split(pat=",") but I don't know how to append it to the existing dataframe since I used """d= df_final['HY_DTM_ID'].str.split(pat=",")""" which just uses the HY_DTM_ID field. I know it is probably basic stuff but how to now use this newly created list as part of the original dataframe or create a new one with all of the needed fields.

Comment: Thanks, yes, that works :) You can put your answer as a solution and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some comment problem was data in column was strings, not lists, so solution is split them by separator and assign back:

```
df_final['HY_DTM_ID'] = df_final['HY_DTM_ID'].str.split(",")
```